# Appropriate choice of k for knn

Tags: machine-learning, classification, knn

I have seen many threads asking for "best choice of knn for my problem X" and I would like a more general answer, so it applies to *any* K-NN classification problem.

1. Should one only care about the **accuracy** of one's model, and therefore *tune* to obtain best possible answer with one's data set?
2. Are there any general problems problem with choosing best possible K for our problem?
3. Does such skill come naturally after building many models, and one can instinctively choose the right value, or at least come up with a sensible range to test through?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `python` or `numpy` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: I'm sorry @desertnaut, I'm new to StackOverflow. 
Where exactly do I post a question like mine then?

Comment: Please notice that when we include a "*please see*" piece of advice, we actually expect that you will actually see it. Please see it.

Answer (score 2):

In general:

1. Too small K (say 1) is sensitive to noisy data i.e. an outlier can heavily influence your model
2. Too large K can lead to misclassification i.e. model gives inaccurate predictions
3. The way you calculate distance matters. For example, in sparse data sets cosine distance will yield much better results than euclidean distance. You could choose a right value for K, but if your distance calculation is irrelevant then the performance of the model is going to be bad anyway.
4. **K equal to number of classes is a very bad choice**, because final classification will be random.

Imagine a binary k-nn classification model, where output is either dog or a cat.
Now imagine you choose k to be equal to 2 (or any other even number).
Also, assume that a data point lies so that it's k nearest neighbours belong to equally one and the other class (two nearest neighbours are both dog and cat or 2 in each class or 3 in each class etc.).
Now, how do you determine which class the point belongs to?

You can't. You would need to randomise the process, or choose the first one, both giving equally bad results.

Answer (score 1):

The K-NN algorithm is a non-parametric machine learning algorithm that is relatively fast and easy to implement. It's fast during training but slow during testing/inference.

Determining the number of **K** really depends on the data set at hand, as it's heavily dependent on the spread (distribution) of your sample points in the decision (feature) space. If the given data set forms a "dense" feature space relative to the number of dimensions (features), then K-NN will work best. However, if the data set results in a sparse feature space, then the K-NN will likely have low accuracy; and opting for another machine learning algorithm will probably be a better option.

As with attempting to find the "best"  **K** for a given data set, it's usually best practice to implement a *k*-fold Cross Validation procedure for different values of **K**, then plot the Accuracy of your model against the number of **K** used for the model. That will generate *k* accuracy values for each chosen value of **K**. The **K** value that results in the highest average accuracy is taken to be the best value of **K** for your model using your specified data set. Such a plot typically (done once) looks something like this:

[image]

(A 10-fold CV is typically used in practice as it gives a good balance of using more samples to generate a more accurate confidence interval and to decrease bias towards estimating "true" error of model)